# Asm intel 64 why decrement before setting

Tags: assembly, intel

I would like to know why i decrement `rax` before setting it to null ?

```
section     .text
    global  _ft_bzero

_ft_bzero:
    cmp     rdi ,   0
    je      end
    mov     rbx ,   rdi
    mov     rax ,   rsi

looop:
    cmp     rax ,   0
    je      end
    dec     rax
    mov     byte [rbx + rax]  , 0
    jmp     looop

end:
    ret
```

Comment: You don't set `RAX` to null, but the memory at position `[rbx + rax]` (successive from back to front).

Comment: @rkhb: That is an answer not a comment, and so belongs as an answer.

Comment: @dave: The comment as answer doesn't meet my requirements (comprehensive information, explanation, example). The question itself is ...ahm... not really great. If it is not upvoted and not answered, it will be deleted in a year or so. That's okay.